# Regular Expression: I have a problem with using '|'

Tags: python, regex

```
text = "a/NNP b/NNG c/NP d/NNP e/PNG"
```

I want to take out words with only 'NNP' and 'NNG' tags.

So I tried:

```
words = re.compile('(\w+/[(NNP)|(NNG)]*)')
t = re.findall(words,text)
```

However, the result keep showing me

```
['a/NNP', 'b/NNG', 'c/NP', 'd/NNP','e/PNG'].
How can I get only ['a/NNP','b/NNG','d/NNP']?
```

Comment: Use `re.compile(r'\w+/NN[PG]\b')`

Comment: Well that case was just an example. I have several tags such as [NNP|NNG|VV|VA|MAG|MAJ|IC|VX|MM], but some tags that are not in the list (for example, NP or VCP or VAX) keep appearing. Can I just get the tag in order?

Comment: Then use `r'\w+/(?:NNP|NNG|all|other|alternatives|here)\b'`. See my answer.

Comment: I use https://rubular.com/ to test the behaviour of regexes to see immediate results. (Although it is "for ruby", it should do the trick here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` denotes a character class. It is not used to group together stuff, like it  is used in maths.

You can use a non-capturing group `(?:)` in place of `[]`:

```
\w+/(?:NNP|NNG)\b
```

If your strings always come in three-character triples, then there is no need for `\b`.

You can add as many options as you want:

```
\w+/(?:NNP|NNG|ABC|DEF|GHI)\b
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
import re

text = "a/NNP b/NNG c/NP d/NNP e/PNG" 
words = re.compile(r'\w+/(?:NNP|NNG)\b')
# OR words = re.compile(r'\w+/NN[PG]\b')
print(re.findall(words,text)) 
# => ['a/NNP', 'b/NNG', 'd/NNP']
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kKIf1k).

The regex is `\w+/NN[PG]\b` see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/5QxGBf/2). It matches

- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (NOTE: to only match *letters*, replace `\w+` with `[^\W\d_]+`)
- `/NN` - `/NN` substring
- `(?:NNP|NNG)` - a non-capturing group matching either  `NNP` or `NNG`
- `[PG]` - either `P` or `G`
- `\b` - a word boundary (in order not to match `/NNGGGG` or whatever).

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help. I never knew what non-capturing group is before.

Comment: @S.joo You may read a lot about [non-capturing groups here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say you need regex for that?

```
stuff = ('NNP', 'NNG')
text = "a/NNP b/NNG c/NP d/NNP e/PNG"
result = [i for i in text.split() if i.split("/")[1] in stuff]
# ['a/NNP', 'b/NNG', 'd/NNP']
```

The above is also more efficient than the regex counterpart and is easier to maintain:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> text = "a/NNP b/NNG c/NP d/NNP e/PNG"
>>> stuff = ('NNP', 'NNG', 'VV', 'VA', 'MAG', 'MAJ', 'IC', 'VX', 'MM')
>>>
>>> def regex(reg):
...     words = re.compile(reg)
...     return re.findall(words,text)
...
>>> def notregex():
...     return [i for i in text.split() if i.split("/")[1] in stuff]
...
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(stmt="regex(a)", setup="from __main__ import regex; a=r'\w+/(?:NNP|NNG|VV|VA|MAG|MAJ|IC|VX|MM)\b'", number=100000)
0.3145495569999639
>>> timeit(stmt="notregex()", setup="from __main__ import notregex", number=100000)
0.21294589500007532
```

Comment: Is there any reason, you are using a list and not a _set_ for this?

Comment: @ThomasJunk No specific reason other than I tend to default to lists more than sets

Comment: @ThomasJunk: If you agree, that a set implies additional overhead, where in the question do you see the justification for it? I would actually be annoyed for a filter removing duplicates without asking for it. A more useful alternative would be a generator, to reduce memory footprint for a high number of results.

Comment: @guidot I think Thomas' suggestion was fair, that's why I changed the list to a set. In the question's context, strings following a specific pattern are being extracted, it means having two identical patterns would not add any additional benefit; and set lookup is faster than list lookup, so...

Comment: @guidot I tend to disagree. The semantics of this is _having a bunch of uniqe criteria_ which is semantically _a set_. I admit, this is a _nitpick_.